# Do they consider typos as misspellings in computer delivered IELTS?

Tags: writing, ielts

I mean there's a difference between a misspelling and a typo, e.g. the word "circulate" is considered misspelled if it's "circilate" or "cerculate", but if it's circukate or cirvulate it's obviously a mistake not because the person doesn't know the spelling, but because he just mistyped it. And my question is how does this affect your score on computer delivered IELTS writing.

Comment: It reduces your score.

Comment: Many people mistype, but sensible people check what they have typed before committing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Typos" and "Spelling mistakes" are both considered inaccuracies and will be treated the same. That is to say, the examiner won't try to analyse if an incorrect spelling is the result of not knowing the correct spelling or keying the incorrect spelling and not checking.   Idp gives [this example](https://assets.ctfassets.net/unrdeg6se4ke/40PDaBgplcQElAbg0yiukY/fe545b694ad773b5be3556a0e517edc0/academic-writing-sample-candidate-responses-and-examiner-comments.pdf) (shortened)

> > The statistice show the number of tripe mad by children in one country over the past to years
> > to travel to end from school using different modes of transport. [...]
>
> [...] There is limited control over spelling, and errors are
> noticeable throughout  (band 3.5)

The word "statistice" may be a typo, or it may be a mistake. The examiner doesn't care. It is inaccurate and loses marks.